# How to map an object tree using ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm trying to map an object tree using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).

I created an example to illustrate my question:

- Class `Sub` contains several properties.
- Class `Source` contains an object of type `Sub` and (at least) another property.
- Class `Destination` holds a flat list of properties.
- The types of source and destination properties differ.

Code:

```
@Test
public class TestCase {

  ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

  class Source {
    String value1 = "1.0";
    Sub sub = new Sub();
  }

  class Sub {
    String sub1 = "2.0";
    String sub2 = "3";
  }

  class Destination {
    float numberOne;
    double numberTwo;
    int numberThree;
  }

  TestCase() {
    modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Sub, Destination>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map(source.sub1, destination.numberTwo);
            map(source.sub2, destination.numberThree);
        }
    });
    modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Source, Destination>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map(source.value1, destination.numberOne);
            // map(source.sub, destination); // this causes an exception
        }
    });
  }

  public void mapSub() { // works
    Destination destination = new Destination();
    modelMapper.map(new Sub(), destination);
    assertEquals(destination.numberTwo, 2d);
    assertEquals(destination.numberThree, 3);
  }

  public void mapSource() { // how to make this work?
    Destination destination = new Destination();
    modelMapper.map(new Source(), destination);
    assertEquals(destination.numberOne, 1f);
    assertEquals(destination.numberTwo, 2d);
    assertEquals(destination.numberThree, 3);
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to configure a single ModelMapper instance so that the following constraints are satisfied:

1. `modelMapper` is able to convert objects of type `Sub` to `Destination`
2. `modelMapper` is able to convert objects of type `Source` to `Destination`
3. the mapping of the properties in `Sub` is declared only once

Unfortunately, the line `map(source.sub, destination);` seems not not work as desired.

My real world scenario contains a bigger object tree with more properties and type conversion. That's the reason why I try to avoid redundant mapping information.

Is it possible to satisfy the constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on this for supporting this by introducing a new API.

```
typeMap.include(Source::getSub, Sub.class)
```

This new API will be included in next release.
Bad new is that you need a getter of this field.

Please refer the issue [#354](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/354) and the pull request [#358](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/pull/358) on github for more detail.